# I get an error when I try to execute this method app.UseCookieAuthentication(); in MVC (.net 5)

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error
> CS1061    'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseCookieAuthentication' and no accessible extension method 'UseCookieAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    IdentityServer  C:\Users\A01\source\repos\Identity provider\src\IdentityServerAspNetIdentity\Startup.cs 189 Active

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0dSb.png)

Comment: Can you post your whole startup.cs file code? it will clarify for understanding your issue.

Comment: Hi @EsraAlshafi, any updates about this case? If the answer could help resolve the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseCookieAuthentication' and no accessible extension method 'UseCookieAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please note that `UseCookieAuthentication` method is obsolete. And it seems be removed from ASP.NET Core 3.0 and above.

You can configure cookie authentication with `AddAuthentication().AddCookie` in `ConfigureServices` method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieappbuilderextensions.usecookieauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Besides, this doc shows how to configure and use cookie authentication, you can refer to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0